# Any good XSLT sheets for XML to PDF?

Tags: xslt, pdf

Does anyone know of a solid non-encumbered suite of XSLT sheets that can generate PDF via an XSL transform?

I really like XSL transforms, I use them to make HTML output from dbms's.

Now I have some data in a DBMS that I like to generate PDF output from. I've not written a dbms to XML script yet for this data, so I have no commitment to any given set of XML tags.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on your XML. If you have, e.g., Docbook, look at [David Pawson's site](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/index.html), for HTML [IBM has a nice example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/) over at developerWorks. Both go the way of XML -> via XSLT -> XSL-FO -> via [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop) -> PDF.

Cheers,